# Express is working with curl but not on react website

Tags: reactjs, express

I am attempting to do a simple website that utilizes react frontend and express backend. Right now the react website is being hosted successfully on a domain I purchased. On the same machine, there is an express server running. I can successfully call it with `curl http://localhost:3000/api`. I've added code to the react front end to console.log the results of the api endpoint. The console is showing me 404 errors from the website. Please help me understand where I have misconfigured.

I have added the line `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000",` to package.json file.

front end

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  fetch('api')
  .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
   })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Site Under Construction
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

back end

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})


// create a GET route
app.get('/api', (req, res) => { //Line 9
  res.send({ express: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT' }); //Line 10
}); //Line 11
```

Comment: Just so I understand the situation right, are you trying to run both the frontend and backend on the same port?

Comment: I don't have a preference. My nginx file for the front end looks like this. I'm just looking for it to work right now and open to suggestions.
```"portfolio"
server {
         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80;
         root /var/www/html/portfolio/;
         index index.html index.htm;
         server_name sample.com;
         location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
         }
}```

Comment: Well the reason I ask is that react uses port 3000 by default and if you're running express on port 3000 as well, they're fighting for that port and it's technically not possible to run 2 servers/apps on the same port on a single machine/container. I suggest switching the express port to something like 3001 and then trying it.

(this comment is only valid if you're not serving static frontend from your server)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed the proxy in package.json to `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",` I also changed the port in back end express file to 3001. I am still seeing the same error.

Comment: can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on codesandbox.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following reverse proxy to my nginx file and it seems to have fixed the issue.

```
         location /api/ {    # Backend
              proxy_pass  http://localhost:3001;
         }
```